# QT5 Migration Cannot open include file: 'QGraphicsWebView'?

Tags: c++, migration, qt5

Simple code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QGraphicsWebView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Sample .pro:

```
QT       += core gui declarative network webkit multimedia

TARGET = QTTest
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
```

And error I get:

```
C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QGraphicsWebView': No such file or directory
```

[What the is going on there in QT5? this class shall Be included like this and so I shall see no such error? I do not get some fancy QT5 new feature?](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qgraphicswebview.html#details)

Answer (score 2):

In the line

```
QT       += core gui declarative network webkit multimedia
```

replace `webkit` by `webkitwidgets` :

```
QT       += core gui declarative network webkitwidgets multimedia
```